# Complex Cubic Equation z^3+3z+2i=0

Tags: complex-numbers

How we can solve the equation $z^3+3z+2i=0$ ?
And is there exist a general method to solve similar equation?

Comment: You could notice that $z=-i$ is a solution. Then, find the quadratic and get the roots.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You mean $z=-i$, no?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this, since $z$ appears only to odd powers, is to set $z=iw$ which enables $i$ to be cancelled and gives you integer coefficients.

Another way is to spot a solution.

The general methods for solving a cubic also work with complex coefficients.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Bennet. What is that method with complex coefficients?

Comment: @MathMan See eg http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:
We have
$$z^3+3z+2i=z(z^2+1)+2(z+i)=z(z+i)(z-i)+2(z+i)=(z+i)(z^2-iz+2)=(z+i)^2(z-2i)=0$$
so our equation has three roots $-i,-i,2i$.